# Verify that given list of nodes of a graph is a correct topological order

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, topological-sort

I've been given a task to write some code that takes in a list of nodes from a graph, and determines whether they are in correct topological order.

The graph is represented in memory as follows:

```
typedef struct graph_t* Graph;
typedef struct node_t* Node;

struct node_t {
    int id;
    /*incoming edges*/
    Linked_list incoming;
    /*outgoing edges*/
    Linked_list outgoing;
};

struct graph_t {
    int order;
    int size;
    Node nodes;
};
```

I omitted the implementation of the linked list for brevity but it is just a standard implementation of a linked list.

I have also been given the following algorithm (pseudocode):

```
L <- topologically sorted list of nodes
V <- empty list of visited nodes
for each node n in L do
    add n to V
    for each node m reachable from n do
        if m in V then L is not sorted
```

I do understand the definition of a topological order, but I don't understand how or why this would verify the topological sort.

How is this algorithm correct? Also, given the above representation of the graph, how would the line `for each node m reachable from n do` be implemented?

Also, is there a better algorithm than the one above to perform this task?

Comment: This is no debugging or consulting service. See [ask].

Comment: @Olaf I wasn't asking how to implement the algorithm, only for an explanation on why it works. Is that against the rules of asking? If so, I will delete my post

Comment: Please read my comment again. I did not state you ask for the implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting CLRS:

> A topological sort of a dag G = (V,E) is a linear ordering of all its vertices such that if G contains an edge (u,v), then u appears before v in the ordering.

This is what you are actually checking in the innermost for loop. If m is reachable from n, but it is already in V, then it means that you have already visited m before visiting n.  Hence L is not topologically sorted.

Answering your next question, you can implement the line

> for each node m reachable from n do

using a DFS or BFS.  So, on node n, you need to check if there is a directed edge which goes from n to m.

Comment: This seems like O(n^2), though sorting topologically  (Khan's or DFS) is much faster. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the idea is based on the following fact:

> Let L be an ordered sequence of vertices of graph G. Then L is a
>   topological order of graph G if and only if all edges in G points in L
>   to the right. In other words, for each directed edge (L[i], L[j]) we have i <
>   j.

In the method you gave, you are making the above check. You check if there is an edge pointing to the left in L, and from the above fact we know that in this case L is not a topological order.